# How can OrientDB support Chinese query?

Tags: orientdb

I am using OrientDB and I have a property name in Chinese.

How can I select this field ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.  Your question is pretty vague. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question. Provide more information and the people here will be eager to help you.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know how to do it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's an issue :

You can create a field in Chinese but you can't select it.

I created a new issue here : https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/7506

Hope it helps